# how to print only the first value in python

Tags: python

In my output file I have:

```
Energy=-0.111....
'other text'
Energy=-0.1223
```

Now I am trying to write a script where I open the output, I read the energy value and print it in another output.

Below is my code

```
with open('.out', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if line.__contains__('Energy'):
        print(line)
```

My problem is that I want in my script print only the first value of energy  Energy=-0.111.... but with my script in the output I have all of them, so it doesn't work. How I can correct my script? I want to understand how I can tell to him to print the first value of Energy in one script and in another only the second one.

Comment: Add a `break` right below `print(line)` (indented the same a the print statement).  That says to stop processing the loop and execution will move to the line following the loop.

Comment: Break outta loop once `line.startswith('Energy')` if you want to print once the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to extend the logic to print the first, second etc times 'Energy' lines are found, you can store them in a list and access whichever one you need to print.

```
data = f.readlines()
energy_lines = []
for line in data:
    if 'Energy' in line:
        energy_lines.append(line)

print(energy_lines[0])  # first line
print(energy_lines[1])  # second line
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use "break" after printing?

```
for line in data:
    if line.__contains__('Energy'):
        print(line)
        break
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using dunders directly like this. Use `in`. I know that the OP used it, but part of the answer should be to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

First observation: Add a break as mentioned by John.

n observation: You could create a counter - if i want the third observation:

```
  data = f.readlines()
  for line in data:
    counter = 0
    if line.__contains__('Energy'):
       counter+=1
       if counter==3:
          print(line)
          break
```

Comment: Did you actually run this? `counter++` isn't valid Python and your indentation is off

Answer (score 0):

If the energy line is always the first line in your text file:

```
with open('.out', 'rt') as f:
    line = next(f)
if 'Energy' in line:
    print(line)
```

If not, then still no point reading in all lines (This should consume less memory and a little less time)

```
num_occurence = 1
match_count = 0
with open('.out', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Energy' in line:
            match_count += 1
            if match_count == num_occurences:
                print(line)
                break
```

I also changed

`if line.__contains__('Energy'):`

into

```
if 'Energy' in line:
```

As one should normally avoid to call magic functions, (less readable and more magic)